# run gitlab with apache

Tags: linux, git, apache, gitlab, ubuntu-20.04

I am trying to run gitlab on ubuntu 20.04 LTS with apache.
I followed the official installation guide: https://about.gitlab.com/install/#ubuntu

When i open my gitlab on git.domain.de i only see the "Deploy in progress" error page.
I see the following error in my logs:

```
[proxy:error] [pid 2267591:tid 139801344845568] (111)Connection refused: AH00957: HTTP: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:8080 (*) failed
[proxy_http:error] [pid 2267591:tid 139801344845568] [client 91.64.235.xxx:51508] AH01114: HTTP: failed to make connection to backend: 127.0.0.1
[proxy:error] [pid 2267592:tid 139801344845568] (111)Connection refused: AH00957: HTTP: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:8080 (*) failed
[proxy_http:error] [pid 2267592:tid 139801344845568] [client 91.64.235.xxx:51513] AH01114: HTTP: failed to make connection to backend: 127.0.0.1, referer: http://git.domain.de/
```

My apache sites-available config looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

  ServerName git.domain.de
  ServerSignature Off

  ProxyPreserveHost On
  AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode

  <Location />
  Require all granted

  ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:8080
  ProxyPassReverse http://git.domain.de
  </Location>

  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule .* http://127.0.0.1:8080%{REQUEST_URI} [P,QSA]

  # needed for downloading attachments
  DocumentRoot /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/public

  #Set up apache error documents, if back end goes down (i.e. 503 error) then a maintenance/deploy page is thrown up.
  ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
  ErrorDocument 422 /422.html
  ErrorDocument 500 /500.html
  ErrorDocument 503 /deploy.html

...

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: any ideas about this?

Comment: did you do 
https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/nginx.html#using-a-non-bundled-web-server
and https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/configuration.html#configuring-the-external-url-for-gitlab

Comment: The answer down here looks like a good resource. I have one question about your question though.... Why would you do that? Nginx is way faster and probably the successor of Apache.

Comment: I would love to use Nginx but unfortunatelly I dont how to do this. When i tried to use Nginx and apache I got always problem with a port alredy in use.

Answer (score 6):

When you run gitlab with Apache you need few more configuration steps.

**Install dependencies**

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
sudo apt-get install curl openssh-server ca-certificates postfix
```

**Configure Gitlab to use Apache**

```
sudo vim /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb
```

Changes needed for the files.

1. Change "nginx['enable'] = true" to "nginx['enable'] = false"
2. Change "web_server['external_users'] = []" to "web_server['external_users'] = ['www-data']"
3. Change "gitlab_rails['trusted_proxies']" to your web servers IP address. e.g. gitlab_rails['trusted_proxies'] = ['10.128.0.2']
4. Change "gitlab_workhorse['listen_network'] = "unix" to gitlab_workhorse['listen_network'] = "tcp"
5. Change gitlab_workhorse['listen_addr'] = "/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-workhorse/socket" to gitlab_workhorse['listen_addr'] = "127.0.0.1:8181"
6. Change "unicorn['port'] = 8080" to "unicorn['port'] = 8082"

Update Gitlab ports Create or edit the file:

```
vim /etc/default/gitlab
```

Add/update below,

```
gitlab_workhorse_options="-listenUmask 0 -listenNetwork tcp -listenAddr 127.0.0.1:8181 -authBackend http://127.0.0.1:8082"
```

**Reload the new Gitlab configuration**

```
sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure
```

**Enable Apache mod_proxy & mod_rewrite**

```
sudo a2enmod proxy; 
sudo a2enmod rewrite; 
sudo a2enmod proxy_http;
```

**Create Apache Config for Gitlab**

```
sudo vim /etc/apache2/sites-available/gitlab.conf
```

**Enable the apache config:**

```
sudo a2ensite gitlab
```

**Restart apache:**

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: I did everything but nothing changed. Still the same error. How should the Apache Config for Gitlab look like?

Comment: Connection refused: AH00957: HTTP: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:8080 (*) failed

Comment: @webGuy did you open the port in apache config to "Listen 8080" ?

Comment: My apache sites-available config looks exactly like postet

Comment: check below link

Comment: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-recipes/-/blob/master/web-server/apache/gitlab-apache24.conf

Comment: For change "unicorn['port'] = 8080" to "unicorn['port'] = 8082" you can change that to puma instead of unicorn.